# sequelize saving multiple objects that assosiates

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I wasnt quite sure what to call this question but here is my setup:

```
var AcademyModule = sequelize.define('academy_module', {
    academy_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    module_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    module_module_type_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    sort_number: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    requirements_id: DataTypes.INTEGER
}, {freezeTableName: true,}
```

With the following `assosiation`:

```
Requirements = sequelize.define('requirements', {
    id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    value: DataTypes.STRING,
    requirement_type_id: DataTypes.INTEGER
}, {freezeTableName: true});

AcademyModule.belongsTo(Requirements, {foreignKey: 'requirements_id'});
```

Now as you can see from my table setup i would have to save a row in `requirements` table and then use the inserted `id` to insert into the `academy_module` table.

for this i created the following:

```
add: function (requirements,academyModule,onSuccess, onError) {
    var academyModule = academyModule;
    if(requirements == null) {
        AcademyModule.build(this.dataValues)
            .save().ok(onSuccess).error(onError);
    } else {
        if(requirements.requirement_type_id == '1') {
            requirements.value = requirements.module.id;
        }
        Requirements.create(requirements).then(function(createdReq) {
            var associationPromises = [];
            associationPromises.push(AcademyModule.create(this.dataValues));

            return sequelize.Promise.all(associationPromises);
        }).success(onSuccess).error(onError);
    }
}
```

However in the `then` function i am unable to reach the `academyModule` object that contains the values that needs to be inserted.

This is a repeating problem for me and i really want to know how it is possible to connect so they do it automatically without doing small `hacks`

i have scouted the documentations but i havnt been able to find a single example of the above (which i find rather odd seeing as this is a fairly normal situation)

**Jan's method**

I tried to solve it using Jan's elegant method

However i am getting an error saying:

```
academy_module is not associated to requirements!
```

My code looks like this as for now:

```
    var academyModule = academyModule;
if(requirements == null)
{
    AcademyModule.build(this.dataValues)
        .save().ok(onSuccess).error(onError);
}
else
{
    requirements.academy_module = academyModule;

    Requirements.create(requirements, {
        include: [AcademyModule]
    });
}
```

Funny thing here is t hat i have the assosiation:

```
AcademyModule.belongsTo(Requirements, {foreignKey: 'requirements_id'});

Requirements.hasOne(AcademyModule, {foreignKey: 'requirements_id'});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I cannot answer why you are having problems accessing `academyModule` - it should be available via simple javascript scoping.

There are some unexplained bits of your code... You are pushing a single promise to `associationPromises` - Why not just return that promise?

You are accessing `this.dataValues` to create an `AcademyModule` instance - `this` will normally be undefined inside a promise handler.

Your issue could be solved more elegantly with nested creation, which is in 2.0.5: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/3386

First of all you need to create the reverse association from Requirements --> AcademyModule

```
Requirements.hasOne(AcademyModule, {foreignKey: 'requirements_id'});
```

This is needed because the Requirement is the 'main model', which is used to create the AcademyModule

```
requirements.academy_module = academy_module;

Requirements.create(requirements, {
  include: [AcademyModule]
});
```

By setting `academy_module` on the requirements object, and adding `include` as the 2nd parameter (similar to how you use includes for `find`) both are created and associated in one go.

You'll need to modify your models slightly. With your current model definition the table will contain an `id` column, but sequelzie does not know that it is the primary key. You either need to remove id completely from the Requirements model (in which case sequelize will add it automatically and mark it as primary key), or add `primaryKey` to it:

```
id: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  primaryKey: true,
  autoIncrement: true // optional - only if you actually want AI :)
}
```

Comment: Hey @Jan first of all thank you for your answer i am trying to solve this using your elegant way however im getting an issue ive update my answer could you take a look :)?

Comment: You need to set up the reverse association (Requirements hasMany / hasOne AcademyModule)

Comment: ive udated my code so you can see the requirements ive added it still does not add (however after the change it does insert into the requirements table)

Comment: i have added your code but it only adds a row in requirements table and not in academy_module

Comment: Hmm, something else must be of then. I've tried verbatim with the models and code you have posted, and it works fine for me. Maybe you can try to recreate the issue as a separate test case, outside your application code, and provide a failing test as a PR on github?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73760/discussion-between-marc-rasmussen-and-jan-aagaard-meier).